# Awk Search and Print Number of Lines Based on a Column of Another File?

Tags: search, join, awk, merge

Say I have 2 files as follows. Basically, I would like to merge the two files but I would like to print number of lines from map.txt based on the 2nd column of filter.txt (please see expected result in output.txt)

```
cat > filter.txt
a    3
b    2
c    6

cat > map.txt
a    a001
a    a002
a    a003
a    a004
a    a005
a    a006
a    a007
a    a008
a    a009
a    a010
a    a011
a    a012
b    b01
b    b02
b    b03
b    b04
c    c01
c    c02
c    c03
c    c04
c    c05
c    c06
c    c07
```

I know there are many ways to do this like while loop but I think an awk command would be more efficient to get this result if I am dealing with thousand of records:

```
output.txt:
a    a001
a    a002
a    a003
b    b01
b    b02
c    c01
c    c02
c    c03
c    c04
c    c05
c    c06
```

I was trying to figure it out from this command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {if(a[b=$1]) {print $0}}' filter.txt map.txt
```

But, it is just printing all the matching lines and I am really stuck on how to control the number of lines to be printed :)

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm curios - what does `b=$1` in your array indexing `a[b=$1]` do for you?

Comment: @Ed Morton, actually since I learned about this trick in awk, I always do that. What I understand is it is another way of merging of two columns from 2 different files.

Comment: No, it doesn't do that. In the script you posted it saves the value of `$1` in the variable `b`, but your script never does anything with `b` so that has no functional effect. I wondered if there was more to your script that you haven't shared with us yet. The script you posted could have been written as just `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a' filter.txt map.txt` to get the same functionality (except if a zero $2 value existed in your first file).

Comment: Thanks Ed. I am just trying to get available IDs from map.txt (e.g. a001, a002 etc...) based on the numbers from filter.txt. Vijay's solution is working. But I think there will be a problem if I have another entry for "a" (e.g. a   2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}(($1 in a) && a[$1]-- >0){print}' filter.txt map.txt
```

Tested:

```
> awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}(($1 in a) && a[$1]-- >0){print}' temp temp1
a    a001
a    a002
a    a003
b    b01
b    b02
c    c01
c    c02
c    c03
c    c04
c    c05
c    c06
>
```

Simplified way:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}(($1 in a) && a[$1]-- >0)' filter.txt map.txt
```

Please check [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/i-have-two-files-file-1-contains-3.html) for more explanation.

Comment: Vijay, this works perfectly! I really appreciate you help. However, I would like to undertand more about this "(($1 in a) && a[$1]-- >0)". What does -- >0 mean? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} a[$1]-- > 0' filter.txt map.txt
```